# Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3' When Using AddExplosionForce

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging

Whenever I press the spacebar, I want an explosive force with an z-axis offset to act on my player. However, it gives me the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            Vector3 rocketLoc = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            rocketLoc.x = rocketLoc.x + 20.00f;
            rb.AddExplosionForce(20.00f, rocketLoc, 20.00f, 20.00f, ForceMode.Impulse);
            StartCoroutine(WaitAfterBlast());
        }
```

Comment: Just btw it should simply be `Vector3 rocketLoc = transform.position;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very self-explainatory; it's is because you cannot convert float to a Vector3. There's no way for the program to assign a `20f` when it expects a `Vector3(x, y, z)`.

There is nothing that will cause an that exception in the code you supplied. If the exception points to this code, it's probably because it isn't the built code, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! I found out that the exception was caused by another file.